# Database Not Updated In Delphi

Tags: delphi, openedge, progress-db

i have an Windows Service made in Delphi 6 that connects to a progress openedge database and transfer the information to a MySQL database one time a day. The problem is, when i start the service, it works fine, but if i update the progress database, in the next day the service still showing the first values (same values). Its like i have an database image and it dont get updated. If i restart the service, they will get the new values, but in the next day will happen the same thing.

For database connection i use TDatabase class.
Anyone knows how to fix this?

This is the code:

```
unit svcMain;

interface

uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, SvcMgr, Dialogs,
    ExtCtrls, AppEvnts, DateUtils, inifiles;

type
    TsvcAgraria = class(TService)
    timAcao: TTimer;
    procedure timAcaoTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServicePause(Sender: TService; var Paused: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceContinue(Sender: TService; var Continued: Boolean);
    function  RightPad(S: string; Ch: Char; Len: Integer): string;
    private
        { Private declarations }
        procedure Gera_log(ctipo,msgtxt:string);
        procedure Replica_Dados();
        procedure Verifica_Ini();
    public
        function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
        { Public declarations }
    end;

var
    svcAgraria: TsvcAgraria;
    lsup1,lsup2,lsupexc,ltudook:boolean;
    cont_registros:integer;
    teste,loteini,lotefim,tLooping:string;

implementation

uses UdtmRamal;

{$R *.DFM}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
    svcAgraria.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TsvcAgraria.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
    Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TsvcAgraria.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
    Gera_Log('INFO','Iniciado o Serviço Windows para Replicação de Ramais.');

    timAcao.Enabled := Started;
end;

procedure TsvcAgraria.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
    timAcao.Enabled := not(Stopped);
    Gera_Log('INFO','Finalizado o Serviço Windows para Replicação de Ramais.');
end;

procedure TsvcAgraria.ServicePause(Sender: TService; var Paused: Boolean);
begin
    timAcao.Enabled := not(Paused);
    Gera_Log('INFO','Serviço Pausado.');
end;

procedure TsvcAgraria.ServiceContinue(Sender: TService;
  var Continued: Boolean);
begin
    timAcao.Enabled := Continued;
    Gera_Log('INFO','Serviço em Execução.');
end;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure TsvcAgraria.timAcaoTimer(Sender: TObject);
    var tagora:string;
begin
    Verifica_Ini();
    tagora := RightPad(IntToStr(HourOf(Now)), '0', 2)  + ':' + RightPad(IntToStr(MinuteOf(Now)), '0', 2);
    //Gera_Log('INFO','Valores à comparar: var "' + tagora + '", ini "' + tLooping + '".');
    if (tLooping = tagora) then
    begin
        Replica_Dados();
    end;
end;
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TsvcAgraria.Replica_Dados();
var
    _validaprof:integer;
begin
    Gera_Log('INFO','--- Iniciando a Replicação de Dados para a Intranet...');
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    try
        dtmAtualizaRamal.DbMyRamal.Connected:=true;
        dtmAtualizaRamal.ConectDBHR.Connected:=true;

        if (dtmAtualizaRamal.ConectDBHR.Connected and dtmAtualizaRamal.DbMyRamal.Connected) then
        begin

        /* BUSINESS LOGIC */

        end;

    except
        on E: Exception do Gera_Log('ERRO',E.Message);
    end;

    Gera_Log('INFO','--- Desconectar Banco.');
    dtmAtualizaRamal.DbMyRamal.Connected:=false;
    dtmAtualizaRamal.ConectDBHR.Connected:=false;
    Gera_Log('INFO','--- Final da Replicação de Dados para a Intranet.');

end;

function TsvcAgraria.RightPad(S: string; Ch: Char; Len: Integer): string;
var
  RestLen: Integer;
begin
  Result  := S;
  RestLen := Len - Length(s);
  if RestLen < 1 then Exit;
  Result := StringOfChar(Ch, RestLen) + S;
end;


procedure TsvcAgraria.Gera_log(ctipo,msgtxt:string);
var
    LogFileName,LogData:string;
    LogFile:TextFile;
begin
    LogFileName := 'c:\datasul\temp\scvRamais.log.txt';
    AssignFile(LogFile, LogFileName);

    //either create an error log file, or append to an existing one
    if FileExists(LogFileName) then
        Append(LogFile)
    else
        Rewrite(LogFile);

    try
        //add the current date/time and the exception message to the log
        LogData := Format('%s : %s : %s',[DateTimeToStr(Now),ctipo,msgtxt]) ;
        WriteLn(LogFile,LogData) ;
    finally
        CloseFile(LogFile);
    end;
end;



end.
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are writing to the database? As it stands now it could be anything...

Comment: Have you committed your transactions?

Comment: @TomBascom Hi Tom, how are you? The values still the same in the progress database and in this base i just read the information. All the creation occurs on the MySQL DB and it's working fine.

Comment: So the issue is that you do not see updates that occur outside of your logic in the Progress database?  As if it is read once and then cached?

Comment: That's right @TomBascom! But i don't know how to solve it. I read about the property keepconnection of the tdatabase, but i don't set this on my service.

Comment: post the code that matters, not the irrelevant stuff

Comment: Hi @Sam, How are you? What is the code that matters? For me, this is the relevant stufff...

Comment: You are having issues with consecutive database writes not being applied (flushed to the database file). The code you posted doesn't even write to the database. Therefore the code you have posted is irrelevant. What you call `Business Logic` is probably where the relevant code is. That's the code you should post for further analysis. Also your DB routine "Replica_Dados" only runs when (tLooping=tagora), but you don't show the code that sets "tLooping"! I'm fine thanks, how are you?

Comment: If the wall of code was more English-friendly I'd be more than happy to debug it, but... Also, reviewing a wall of code to find a bug isn't really the StackOverflow way of doing things.

Comment: A more important note that you should consider is that when you make a service, you really shouldn't implement your logic inside the service thread. It's extremely recommended practice to build your own worker thread which encapsulates all your business logic, and then spawn that thread from your service. The same thread can then also be used in other test applications when you're developing it. It's really difficult to debug something when it's in a service... Whenever I make a service, I make param switches to run my service as a test application with real-time logging.

Comment: You left out all the data access code. If you're having problems with reading or writing to a database it helps if you post the code that's actually interacting with the database. The code you posted doesn't even touch the database.